# I cannot display video fullscreen in a VideoView of Android

Tags: android, fullscreen, android-videoview

I have following code to show video in fullscreen in Android app.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fancy="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:materialdesign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/firstRunBackground"
android:gravity="center">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/firstRunBackground"
    android:gravity="center">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
```

Height matches the parent, but width is 1/3 of the screen.

How can I make it fullscreen?